# Prevent User saving excel document back to Sharepoint

Tags: wss-3.0, excel

I have users on Excel 2010 and they are accessing a sharepoint site using Sharepoint Services 3.0 and clicking on the excel document and the default behaviour is to save this back to sharepoint rather than their local machine.

This causes many instances of the same document to exist on the site. This is for users in a Bank and they wouldn't be very technical.

Appreciate any inputs you might have.

Answer (score 0):

Since only **authorized** users are able to save new (or updated) items and documents, you can reach your goal **changing the library permissions**.
In this way you can **exclude** some users or a group from editing (they can edit their **local** copy but won't be able to save it on SP). 
So you have to decide which user or group is authorized to save and who is not, you put the first in the **editors group** (ususally "members"), the second in the **visitors** one.
Probably you have to "delete unique permission" in site permission(In case you may create new SP groups).
In this way "common" users will be able to open, download but not to save files.

Comment: Please add more details to this answer, it lacks details about how to perform what you propose

Comment: Appreciate the inputs and I get what you're pointing at. The user has it hosted on another site which I think is a link to sharepoint and they don't have the option to save to sharepoint anymore. They were unwilling to do more tests but appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

This may occur because of The WebClient service was stopped or not installed on each WFE SharePoint Server in the farm.

- Try to start it by running services.msc , and you can also check the same scenario at [Can not save a document back into document library in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/01/31/can-not-save-document-back-into-document-library-in-sharepoint-2010/)
- If you can't find WebClient service, try to install it at all WFE SharePoint servers within farm as mentioned [here](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/03/24/add-desktop-experience-feature-on-windows-server-2012/)